# Get data from two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

One holds questions:

```
id | question
1   How old are you?
2   Are you male of female?
```

The other holds exams:

```
id  |   title     |  question_ids
1    Summer Exam     [1,2]
```

My question is, I want to select an exam from the exams table, and get all of the questions related to that particular exam (the question_ids field), but get the question from the question table and not just the id stored in question_ids.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you store in the questions table the id of the exam which the question belongs to it will be much easier to find out the answer :P

Comment: you really show use a weak entity to store the `question_IDs`. This is very poor database design the way it is constructed.

Comment: Don't store `[1,2]` in your database.  Instead make a link table `examQuestions`, that has the `examID` and each of its `questionIDs`.

Comment: Yes as @RocketHazmat said its not good practice to store multiple values in it. Create one more table for linking like: mapping (ExamId, QueId) and by using joins you can get what you want and it will be easy with good db design

Comment: I haven't seen date of que. I am late here 

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FIND_IN_SET` command. Note that this will NOT use your indexes, so it may be pretty slow

```
SELECT title, question
FROM questions
INNER JOIN exams
ON FIND_IN_SET(questions.id, exams.question_ids)
```

You could also use an `IN`. Note that this will only work when selecting a specific exam. Without selecting a specific exam you will return every record referenced in the question_ids column in the entire exams table

```
SELECT title, question
FROM questions, exams
WHERE exams.id = 1
AND questions.id IN (question_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need to provide an id of the exam so the second solution is perfect, but I can seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change your id column in your question table to be q_id and question_id to also be called q_id so you have a clear way to link your tables. Change your id column to be  called exam_id for instance and then your names are less confusing. Then you can use an inner join for instance...

```
SELECT q.q_id, q.question, e.exam 
FROM questions q 
 INNER JOIN exams e ON q.q_id=e.q_id 
WHERE ......
```

Something like that.